# AngularJS "Dynamic" / "Wildcard" routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application, browser-history

I am using angular ui router like following:

```
angular
  .module('app', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('start', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/start.html',
        controller: 'startCtrl'
      })
      .state('dictionary', {
        url: '/dictionary',
        templateUrl: 'templates/dictionary.html',
        controller: 'dictionaryCtrl'
      })
  }])
```

This works just fine.

Now what I would like to do is to continue building the URL from /dictionary.

Basically the dictionary will contain a repeated set of li elements which are rendered based on an array of objects.
Note that the array of objects are retrieved from a source which may contain a different set of objects from time to time.

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="element in array">
          {{element}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

By clicking an element in the above list the controller will update the array and re-render the above list based on childelements to corresponding element in the source.

#### Now to the problem

First I would like the url to be appended like:

```
/dictionary/selectedelement
```

If I then would hit back in my browser I wish to return to

```
/dictionary
```

and if I were to bookmark

```
/dictionary/selectedelement
```

I wish to be able to render the list based on that last url segment.

I would also like to use the same controller if at all possible.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a hierarchy of items? Level 1 (just under root) displayed on `/dictionary` and subtrees displayed on `/dictionary/nodeXId/nodeYId/...` etc.?

Comment: what's wrong with using `/dictionary/:selectedelement`?  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting it right, you have a list of dynamic states and you want to use the same controller.

Something like

```
/dictionary/my-first-element
/dictionary/my-second-element
```

Is that right?

Well, that's exactly what we are using on Wishtack.com to handle i18n urls.

We have an utils service with a method that generates states from a configuration object.

In your case it would simply look something like this (as we are using underscore.js):

```
stateList = _.map(stateConfigList, function (stateConfig) {
  return {
    controller: 'YourGenericController',
    name: stateConfig.name,
    url: '/dictionary/' + stateConfig.url,
    /* You can add any field you want so you can have different behaviours depending on the state using the same controller. */
    settings: stateConfig.settings
  }
});

angular.forEach(stateList, function (state) {
  $stateProvider.state(state.name, state);
});
```

Your controller can have different behaviours per state:

```
$scope.showCrazyStuff = $state.current.settings.showCrazyStuff;
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Concerning the back button, you can override the history using:

```
 $window.history.pushState()
```

But IMHO, I think that it's hacky because if I come from another website on your /dictionary/my-first-element and I hit back, I would expect my browser to go back to the website I came from and not to /dictionary. As a user, I would feel kidnapped.

One last thing, as the state configuration is performed using $stateProvider during the config phase and before service injections, AFAIK, I don't think there's a clean way to add and remove states dynamically while your controllers are running. By the way, it would be weird to have this kind of behaviours as again, if I come from an external website, angular-ui-router should already know all possible states in order to know which controller it should run, otherwise, I would be redirected to the default state.

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE:**

Oh ! I was thinking about something easier. Why don't you declare one state like this { url: '/dictionary/:itemId' } Then in your controller, you can user "$stateParams.itemId" to know which element the user is looking for.

The main advantage of the first solution is that you can assign different controller/template pairs to a group of URLs.

On Wishtack, we also use a trick that can use different controllers depending on the context with something like this:

```
.controller('Controller', function ($stateParams) {
  if ($stateParams...) {
     /* Yes, we use classes using dejavu and ControllerOne and ControllerTwo extend a base class ControllerBase. */
     return new ControllerOne();
  }
  else {
     return new ControllerTwo();
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh ! I was thinking about something easier.

Why don't you declare one state like this
{
  url: '/dictionary/:itemId'
}

Then in your controller, you can user "$stateParams.itemId" to know which element the user is looking for.